# How to update div of one .aspx page from another .aspx page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am new to asp.net and working through a problem set that has two .aspx pages.

**Events.aspx:**

This is where the site-admin updates the upcoming events and webinars with the help of already available panel like, title of the event,date, information, etc.

**index.aspx:**

It is my homepage that has a div section on the sidebar where I want those updated events from the 
**Events.aspx** to be reflected. It will show only the top four upcoming events.

They will be sorted according to the latest upcoming events to the later ones.

In the future when these events are updated, only the top four upcoming events will be displayed.

How to go about it? Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Store the HTML content of the div (the content which the 'admin' has written) inside some kind of database (Sql, MySql). Then when users load your other page you  will load the content stored in the database into the div (perhaps using HtmlString)

Comment: Seems good. Also, is there a way that when the database is updated with new content, it gets updated my homepage without having to load the page.

Comment: You could use java script and ajax to refresh the content of your div.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using Simple [Events and delegate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4773/Events-and-Delegates-Simplified) concept. Publish event from your `Event.aspx` and you can subscribe that in your `Index.aspx` page. `Delegate` will be act as a communication channel between `Event` and `Event handler`.

Comment: Thank you Mukesh, I'll try it and hopefully implement it to.